# Is dataURL image always loaded before a JavaScript module?

Tags: javascript

In the following code, is there always a guarantee that the image content will be ready before the module execution starts or do I need an 'onload' event handler?

```js
<body>

    <script type="module">

        const get = id => document.getElementById(id);

        const imgToCanvas = id => {
            const img = get(id);
            const [w, h] = [img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight];
            img.setAttribute('width', w);
            img.setAttribute('height', h);
            const canv = get('canv');
            canv.setAttribute('width', w);
            canv.setAttribute('height', h);
            const ctx = canv.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        }

        imgToCanvas('img');

    </script>

    <canvas id="canv" style="border: solid 1px #333;"></canvas>

    <img id="img" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAA...">

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an onload event, the loading of the image is done asynchronously, whatever the source and isn't tied to any rule as to when it will actually happen.

This is thus complete undefined behavior, and the only way to have a deterministic behavior is to use the load event.